# Who were the scholars responsible for the New English Translation?

Tags: bible-versions, new-english-translation

According to [Bible.org](http://bible.org/netbible/), in the section entitled "Preface,"

> [The NET Bible] was completed by more than 25 scholars – experts in the original biblical languages – who worked directly from the best currently available Hebrew, Aramaic, and Greek texts.

Where can one find a list identifying these scholars responsible for producing the New English Translation?

Comment: I couldn't find this anywhere either.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The NET Bible® Team
First Edition Translators, Editors, and Consultants
Old Testament Translators and Editors

Pentateuch:

- Richard E. Averbeck, Ph.D. (Dropsie College)﻿
- Robert B. Chisholm, Th.D.  (Dallas Theological Seminary)
- Dorian Coover-Cox, Ph.D.  (Dallas Theological Seminary)
- Eugene H. Merrill, Ph.D. (Columbia University)
- Allen P. Ross,  Ph.D. (Cambridge University)

Historical Books:

- Robert B. Chisholm, Th.D.  (Dallas Theological Seminary)
- Dorian Coover-Cox, Ph.D.  (Dallas Theological Seminary)
- Gordon H. Johnston, Th.D.  (Dallas Theological Seminary)
- Richard A. Taylor, Ph.D.  (Catholic University of America)

Wisdom Books:

- Robert B. Chisholm, Th.D.  (Dallas Theological Seminary)
- Gordon H. Johnston, Th.D.  (Dallas Theological Seminary)
- Allen P. Ross, Ph.D. (Cambridge University)
- Steven H. Sanchez, Ph.D.  (Dallas Theological Seminary)

Major and Minor Prophets:

- William D. Barrick, Th.D.  (Grace Theological Seminary)
- M. Daniel Carroll R., Ph.D.  (University of Sheffield)
- Robert B. Chisholm, Th.D.  (Dallas Theological Seminary)
- Dorian Coover-Cox, Ph.D.  (Dallas Theological Seminary)
- Donald R. Glenn, M.A. (Brandeis University)
- Michael A. Grisanti, Ph.D.  (Dallas Theological Seminary)
- W. Hall Harris III, Ph.D. (University of Sheffield)
- Eugene H. Merrill, Ph.D. (Columbia University)
- Steven H. Sanchez, Ph.D.  (Dallas Theological Seminary)
- Brian L. Webster, Ph.D. (Hebrew Union College - Jewish Institute of Religion)

New Testament Translators and Editors
Gospels and Acts:

- Darrell L. Bock, Ph.D. (University of Aberdeen)
- Michael H. Burer, Ph.D.  (Dallas Theological Seminary)
- W. Hall Harris III, Ph.D. (University of Sheffield)
- Gregory J. Herrick, Ph.D.  (Dallas Theological Seminary)
- David K. Lowery, Ph.D. (University of Aberdeen)

Pauline Letters:

- John D. Grassmick, Ph.D. (University of Glasgow)
- W. Hall Harris III, Ph.D. (University of Sheffield)
- Gregory J. Herrick, Ph.D.  (Dallas Theological Seminary)
- Harold W. Hoehner, Ph.D. (Cambridge University)
- David K. Lowery, Ph.D. (University of Aberdeen)
- Jay E. Smith, Ph.D.  (Trinity Evangelical Divinity School)

General Letters and Revelation:

- Buist M. Fanning III, D.Phil. (Oxford University)
- W. Hall Harris III, Ph.D. (University of Sheffield)
- Gregory J. Herrick, Ph.D.  (Dallas Theological Seminary)
- David K. Lowery, Ph.D. (University of Aberdeen)
- Daniel B. Wallace, Ph.D.  (Dallas Theological Seminary)

Translation Consultants

- Wayne Leman, M.A. (University of Kansas)
- James Routt, Ph.D. (Cambridge University)

English Style Consultant

- W. Hall Harris III, Ph.D. (University of Sheffield)

NET Bible Executive Steering Committee

- W. Hall Harris III, Ph.D.,  Project Director and Managing Editor
- Michael H. Burer, Ph.D.,  Editor and Assistant Project Director
- Robert B. Chisholm, Th.D., Senior OT Editor
- Daniel B. Wallace, Ph.D., Senior NT Editor
- Buist M. Fanning, Ph.D., NT Editor
- Donald R. Glenn, M.A., OT Editor
- Gordon H. Johnston, Th.D., OT Editor
- Steven H. Sanchez, Ph.D., OT Editor
- Richard A. Taylor, Ph.D., OT Editor

Project Management and Production

- W. Hall Harris III, Ph.D.,  Project Director and Managing Editor
- Michael H. Burer, Ph.D.,  Editor and Assistant Project Director
- J. Hampton Keathley IV, Th.M.,  Technical Director
- Todd Lingren, M.A., Director of Publication

Due to the rapidly expanding list of endorsements of the NET Bible, a current list may be seen at www.bible.org/endorse.
The current list of editors and contributors may be seen at www.bible.org/editors.